# Is there a problem with ctrl-shift-F10 shortcut when using FreeCommander and IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, freecommander, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and FreeCommander at the same time.
In IDEA the keyboard shortcut ctrl-shift-F10 is standard for running unit tests.
This works fine, except if I have FreeCommander running at the same time.

If FreeCommander is running and I press ctr-shift-F10, the mouse pointer turns into crosshairs, and nothing happens until I click something. When I do the FreeCommander is sent to the front.

I have tried to look for keyboard shortcuts, and configure them  in FreeCommander but I haven't found anything, and I can't figure out what operation FreeCommander tries to do when the mouse pointer is crosshairs.

I would appreciate any help.

PS: I do not want to change the keyboard shortcut for running unit tests in IntelliJ IDEA, as ctrl-shift-F10 is a company standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In FreeCommander, go to Extras -> Desktop Snapshot. Then remove the hotkey.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, this has been bugging me for over a year.

Comment: Glad I could help :)